# Can options change `sat` into `unsat`?

Tags: z3

Another question from a Z3 newbie. Can options change the behavior of Z3? I might expect them to affect termination, or change `sat` or `unsat` into `unknown` but not `sat` into `unsat` or vice versa.

This example:

```
(set-option :smt.macro-finder true)

(declare-datatypes () ((Option (none) (some (Data Int)))))

(define-sort Set () (Array Option Option))
(declare-fun filter1 (Option) Option)
(declare-fun filter2 (Option) Option)

(declare-var s1 Set)
(declare-var s2 Set)
(declare-var x1 Option)
(declare-var x2 Option)
(declare-var x3 Option)
(declare-var x4 Option)

(assert (not (= x1 none)))
(assert (not (= x2 none)))
(assert (not (= x3 none)))
(assert (not (= x4 none)))
(assert (= (select s1 x1) x2))
(assert (= (select s2 x3) x4))

(assert (forall ((x Option)) (= (filter1 x) (ite (or (= none x) (= (Data x) 1)) x none))))
(assert (forall ((x Option)) (= (filter2 x) (ite (or (= none x) (= (Data x) 2)) x none))))

(assert (= ((_ map filter1) s1) s2))
(assert (= ((_ map filter2) s1) s2))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

returns `sat` with the first line and `unsat` without it.

Is this a bug or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Yes, toggling between sat/unsat based only on options is a bug (soundness).  Toggling between sat/unknown, unsat/unknown, terminates with any answer/no termination, are not bugs

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. The two quantifiers are essentially providing "definitions" for `filter1` and `filter2`.
The option `smt.macro-finder` is used to eliminate functions symbols by expanding these definitions. It is essentially performing "macro expansion". However, there is a bug in the macro expander. It does not expand the occurrences of `filter1` and `filter2` in the map constructs: `(_ map filter1)` and `(_ map filter2)`.

This bug will be fixed.
In the meantime, we should not use the `map` construct and `smt.macro-finder` option simultaneously.